# Rainbow screen in python

Tags: python, pygame

As a project, I'm trying to make a screen that will flash random colors every tenth of a second or so.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import pygame, random
from threading import Timer

background_colour = (random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))
(width, height) = (300, 200)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Rainbow!!!')
screen.fill(background_colour)


pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
pygame.quit()
```

It opens a screen with a random background. But I've tried lots of methods for my next step. A little help?

Answer (score 2):

**Before running this make note that it contains rapid flashing colours**

You need to change the variable `background_colour` every tenth of a second

a simple program that achieves the desired result:

```
import pygame
import random

window_x = 300
window_y = 200

def get_rand_colour():
    colour_r = random.randint(0,255)
    colour_g = random.randint(0,255)
    colour_b = random.randint(0,255)
    return (colour_r,colour_g,colour_b)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_x,window_y))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rainbow!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False
counter = 0
colour = get_rand_colour()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    counter += 1
    if counter > 3:
        colour = get_rand_colour()
        counter = 0

    screen.fill(colour)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Hope this helps :)